# How many instances one can have of an anonymous class?

Tags: java, anonymous-class

An anonymous class is something like this:

```
  SenseOfLife _42 = new SenseOfLife() {
    public int eval() {
       return 42;
    }
  };
```

I didn't understand why such an anonymous class can have an unbounded number of instances (this is a proposition).

While I'm defining this anonymous class it creates automatically an instance and assigns it to the variable `_42`. So I have only one instance and cannot create a new instance.

Comment: Please rephrase this with the question in the body of the... question (not only the title.)

Comment: the answer is only one, in your code.. or in a for loop n times

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4820031/re-more-than-one-instance-of-an-anonymous-inner-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create multiple instances by:

- Executing the same block of code more than once.
- Cloning an instance of an anonymous class.

Comment: And, reflection? Could you add it to your post?

Answer (score 2):

If the interface extends `Cloneable` the class could technically be cloned.

Reflection could get a new instance.

If the same `new SenseOfLife()` constructor is called in a loop that constructor will get compiled down to one class that is instantiated multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but most likely you can create other instances using reflection, i.e., `instance.getClass().newInstance()`.